Какая тут должна быть пунктуация? Вводные слова
Правильно ли так?
К сожалению, а может быть, к счастью, в Петербурге они не встретились.

Правильно:
К сожалению, а может быть, к счастью, в Петербурге они не встретились.
Пояснение
Здесь единая вводная конструкция, дополнительные знаки не нужны.
Сочетание а может быть  — это единое сочетание, которое дифференцирует значение второго вводного слова к счастью.
ПАС § 95
Запятая после союза не ставится, если союз включается во 
вводную конструкцию, образуя с ней единое сочетание (изъятие 
вводного слова невозможно): В темном тумане начали 
появляться обрывочные и бессвязные видения, настолько 
бессвязные и далекие одно от другого, точно они слетались ко 
мне от разных людей, а может быть, и не только от людей 
(Расп.); Шла жизнь, может быть, веселая и светлая, а может 
быть, скудная и молчаливая (Пауст.); 

